# Yoast SEO breaks custom rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I've got a class which generates custom rewrites in a loop.

Like the following for example

```
foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $cityRewrite = sprintf('^(%s)/(%s)?$', substr($permalink['permalink'],1), $page->post_name);
    $cityRewriteLocation = sprintf('index.php?page_id=%s&city=%s', $page->ID, $permalink['city_id']);
    add_rewrite_rule($cityRewrite, $cityRewriteLocation,'top');
}
```

This works well, and generates more than a few rewrites.

`wp-cli rewrite list` is in the following format:

```
^(the-city)/(checkout)?$ | index.php?page_id=[integer-here]&city=[uuid-here]
...
```

Something broke today and suddenly all pages returned 404.
Hours later i find out that this is caused by the plugin Yoast SEO which seems to elimitate all the rewrites created by my custom class.

So my questions are.

- Am i doing something wrong by running this custom rewrite loop hooked on the wordpress **'init'** action?
- Are you supposed to handle custom rewrites differently when using Yoast SEO?
- Could this just be a bug in Yoast SEO?